# how can put navigation view when is open on bottom navigaion view?

Tags: java, android, devexpress

i want to set navigation view when is open on bottom navigation but i dont khow how do it.i set image below look that i want to dont be navigation behind the bottom navigation but i dont khow i think should customize navigation view and use it instead android navigation view
this is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
tools:openDrawer="start">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/darkGray"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_navigation_header"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/darkGray"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation_main"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_item_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_item_color"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and this is my MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupToolbar();
        setupBottomNavigation();
    }

    private void setupToolbar() {
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                drawerLayout, toolbar, 0, 0);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    private void setupBottomNavigation() {
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);
        bottomNavigationView = (AHBottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation_main);


        AHBottomNavigationItem item1 = new AHBottomNavigationItem(R.string.bottom_navigation_home, R.drawable.ic_home, R.color.navigation_item_color);
        AHBottomNavigationItem item2 = new AHBottomNavigationItem(R.string.bottom_navigation_message, R.drawable.ic_home, R.color.navigation_item_color);
        AHBottomNavigationItem item3 = new AHBottomNavigationItem(R.string.bottom_navigation_Accounting, R.drawable.ic_home, R.color.navigation_item_color);
        AHBottomNavigationItem item4 = new AHBottomNavigationItem(R.string.bottom_navigation_archive, R.drawable.ic_home, R.color.navigation_item_color);


        bottomNavigationView.addItem(item1);
        bottomNavigationView.addItem(item2);
        bottomNavigationView.addItem(item3);
        bottomNavigationView.addItem(item4);

        bottomNavigationView.setCurrentItem(0, true);

        bottomNavigationView.setDefaultBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

        bottomNavigationView.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#fdfdfe"));
        bottomNavigationView.setInactiveColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));

        bottomNavigationView.setTitleState(AHBottomNavigation.TitleState.ALWAYS_SHOW);


        bottomNavigationView.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        //transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, new Fragment_home());
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, new Fragment_Message());
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, new Fragment_Message());
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                       // transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, new Fragment_Message());
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                }
                transaction.commit();
                return true;
            }

        });


    }

}
```

i want to put navigation in front of bottom navigation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
  findViewById(R.id.drawer_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open right drawer
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    });

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

**Here is complete reference**

https://v4all123.blogspot.in/2016/03/simple-example-of-navigation-view-on.html